# How can I upload a new revision to an specific file in Google Drive using the REST API?

Tags: rest, post, google-drive-api

I have a time reading official documentation, blogs and googling without success.
Google Drive documentation is available here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/patch
According to documentation, available rest endpoints are "delete", "get", "list", "patch" and "update".

I'm trying to add **revisions** to a file that already exists in Google Drive.

As a problem condition, I should not use and SDK.

Just to illustrate the idea, this is the post request that I used to upload a file:

```
POST /upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_file
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create a 'revision' of the file as soon as the file is created? If this is the case, when the file is created, it will already have a revision. You can list these revisions with the list method.

Comment: Actually I would like to add any revisions as I need. 
The upload POST was just to highlight the point that I'm not using an SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update update documentation. There explains how to use **pinned** and **newRevision** optional parameters.

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/{fileId}&pinned=true
```

I sent the new file content in the body of the request (just like to upload a new file). You can read the documentation if you want a custom behavior (for example you can use another endpoint to update the metadata of a file).